# Load a new JPanel into an existing JPanel

Tags: java

Good Afternoon, I'm back with another new-bee question. I am trying to create an program with a Star Trek inspired interface. I do not want to use dialog boxes with the program.
My interface is drawn on the screen in the fraMain class that my program calls first. It is shown below:

```
/**
 * Troy Marker Enterprises
 * TMEA-002-J: PHMS Database - Java
 * Main Activity Code File
 * Copyright (c) 2020 By Troy Marker Enterprises
 * All Rights Under Copyright Reserved
 *
 * The code in this file was created for use with Troy Marker Enterprises Software.
 * Use of this code by the public is strictly prohibited.
 */
package com.troymarkerenterprises;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

/**
 * Main program frame class
 */
public class fraMain extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    /**
     * Program variable definitions
     */
    private JPanel panMainMenu;
    public static JPanel panSubMenu;
    public static JPanel panTop;
    private JPanel panBottom;
    private int screenWidth;
    private int screenHeight;




    /**
     * Method to start the program
     * @param args  - Method arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new fraMain();
    }

    /**
     * Method to draw the main window
     */
    public fraMain() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(this::run);
    }

    /**
     * Draw the main window
     */
    private void run() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        GraphicsEnvironment graphics = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice device = graphics.getDefaultScreenDevice();
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
        screenWidth = gd.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
        screenHeight = gd.getDisplayMode().getHeight();
        this.panMainMenu = new ClassMainMenu(screenWidth, screenHeight);
        panSubMenu = new ClassSubMenu(screenWidth, screenHeight);
        panSubMenu.setVisible(false);
        panTop = new ClassTopFrame(screenWidth,screenHeight);
        this.panBottom = new ClassBottomFrame(screenWidth, screenHeight);
        this.add(this.panMainMenu);
        this.add(panSubMenu);
        this.add(panTop);
        this.add(panBottom);
        this.pack();
        this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        device.setFullScreenWindow(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


    }

}
```

The screen is divided into four panels: panMainMenu, panSubMenu, panTop, and panBotom.

Each panel has its own class that draw its contents.

The panSubMenu is hidden until a button in the Main Menu is pressed, which show the sub menu. That part is working fine.

However, when I click the Exit Button on the main menu the only t hing that  happens is the top frame turns white.

Here is my code for the Main Menu:

```
package com.troymarkerenterprises;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class ClassMainMenu extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    final TMButton department;
    final TMButton grade;
    final TMButton user;
    final TMButton exit;
    private String MainMenuOption;
    private final int screenHeight;
    private final int screenWidth;

    public ClassMainMenu(int screenWidth, int screenHeight) {
        this.screenWidth = screenWidth;
        this.screenHeight = screenHeight;
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        this.setBounds(0, 0, 160, screenHeight);
        department = new TMButton("DEPARTMENT", "green");
        grade = new TMButton("GRADES", "green");
        user = new TMButton("USERS", "green");
        exit = new TMButton("EXIT","blue");
        department.addActionListener(this);
        grade.addActionListener(this);
        user.addActionListener(this);
        exit.addActionListener(this);
        this.add(department);
        this.add(grade);
        this.add(user);
        this.add(exit);

    }

    public void deselectAll() {
        for (Component c : this.getComponents()) {
            if (c instanceof TMButton) {
                ((TMButton)c).setSelected(false);
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ClassTopFrame topFrame = new ClassTopFrame();
        if(e.getSource()==department) {
            this.deselectAll();
            fraMain.panSubMenu.setVisible(true);
            department.setSelected(true);
            MainMenuOption = "Department";
        }
        if(e.getSource()==grade) {
            this.deselectAll();
            fraMain.panSubMenu.setVisible(true);
            grade.setSelected(true);
            MainMenuOption = "Grade";
        }
        if(e.getSource()==user) {
            this.deselectAll();
            fraMain.panSubMenu.setVisible(true);
            user.setSelected(true);
            MainMenuOption = "User";
        }
        if(e.getSource()==exit) {
            this.deselectAll();
            exit.setSelected(true);
            fraMain.panTop = topFrame.exitProgram(fraMain.panTop);
            //System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

And the code for the top panel:

```
package com.troymarkerenterprises;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Objects;

public class ClassTopFrame extends JPanel{

    private int screenWidth;
    private int screenHeight;

    public ClassTopFrame(int Width, int Height) {
        screenWidth = Width;
        screenHeight = Height;
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        this.setBounds(160, 0, screenWidth-160, screenHeight/2);
        JLabel jl=new JLabel();
        jl.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource("/i_TMEA-0002-J_Logo.png"))));
        this.add(jl);
    }

    public ClassTopFrame() {

    }

    public JPanel exitProgram(JPanel returnPanel) {
        returnPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        returnPanel.setBounds(160, 0, screenWidth-160, screenHeight/2);
        JLabel jl=new JLabel();
        jl.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource("/i_TMEA-0002-J_Logo.png"))));
        returnPanel.add(jl);
        return returnPanel;
    }
}
```

My plan is the have a new panel replace the top panel when the Exit button is pressed. I know the current code will only display the same  contents of the panel when the button is clicked, it just wanted to put something the int exitProgram method for it to display.

As I said, I am a Java new-bee. I am not even sure if what I want to do is possible, I want to think so. Can anyone help me figure this out?

Thanks, Troy

Here is a picture of what I am looking to do:
[image: The interface I am looking for]

The right side of the screen will show the sub menu when one of the buttons is clicked.

ADDITION:

In response to some help I have been getting, I am trying to switch to a card layout, but am having problem. I tried posting here, but it looks like adding the required information will make this post to long. So I uploaded everything to my GitHub account. The main changes I made are in this fine: https://github.com/troy-marker/TMEA-0002-J/blob/main/src/com/troymarkerenterprises/ClassBottomFrame.java

Comment: I see setBounds methods.  SetBounds methods are not good coding practice.  Swing was designed to be used with [layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response. As I said, I am new to Java. Can you suggest a better way to create the screen I am looking for?

Comment: Sure.  Show us a picture of what you want.  Your description is lacking enough detail for me to visualize your GUI.  In the meantime, bookmark the Oracle tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Netbeans section.

Comment: Okay, now we have a partial idea of what you want.  What happens in the middle of this huge screen?  What are all the different ways that your GUI image will look?

Comment: After you click on one of the buttons, a submenu appears on the right side of the screen. When you click on the submenu button, the middle of the screen shows a list on the bottom, and a form or a message dialog on the top. I know it seems like that you will be moving the mouse a lot, but I am looking forward to the time I can run the program on a touch screen. Also, I am taking your suggestion and looking into other layout options. I looked at the link you suggested, but I do not use Netbeans, I use IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate.

Comment: The answer to your original question, How do I load a new JPanel into an existing JPanel, is to use a [Card layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).  Generally, you construct the entire GUI before you display anything.  The Oracle tutorials work for all IDEs.

Comment: I did get they layout changed so I am not using the setBounds statement. I switched it to a GridBoxLayout. Thanks for the suggestion. I will look at the Card Layout next.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236295/discussion-between-troy-marker-and-gilbert-le-blanc).